# How to perform If statement using Lambda java 8 on an employee object

Tags: java, lambda

Hello guys I'm new to Java8 and lambda below is the code for employee and employee list. I created an employee class with name and age and would like to print out the names of the employee whose age is greater than 40.

```
 public class EmployeeAge {


    public static class Employee{
        String name;
        int age;

        public Employee (String name , int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(new Employee("xxa", 40));
        employees.add(new Employee("xxz",25));
        employees.add(new Employee("xxy", 41));
        employees.add(new Employee("xxu", 53));
        employees.add(new Employee("xxx", 13));
        employees.add(new Employee("xxe", 73));
        employees.add(new Employee("yyy", 63));
        employees.add(new Employee("eee", 60));

        for(int i=0; i < employes.size();i++ )
        {
            if(employes.get(i).age > 40)
            {
               System.out.println(employes.get(i).getName());
            }
            else{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i use the lambda for the for loop and if else statement and print the required out put.

Comment: set your class fields to `private`.  you shouldn't be trying to access it as follows `employes.get(i).age`. plus you've got getters for the fields so use it.

Comment: Yup did that thank you for pointing it out. The employee object name is wrong as well. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible way to write the `for` loop using Java 8 streams and lambdas:

```
employes.stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getAge() > 40)  // filter employees with age > 40
    .map(Employee::getName)        // obtain each employee's name
    .forEach(System.out::println); // finally, print it
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Can you suggest any tutorials or resources where I can learn java lambdas.

Comment: I did that as well. But a popup showed "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @NitinCheekatla sure, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes, you're right. Done! we don't want to discourage new users.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash did that. Thank you.

Comment: If we wants to edit age by increasing one then what changes needed?

Answer (score 2):

You have to obtain a stream of your list of employees and apply a filter to reject age more than 40. You need JDK8 or above too

```
employes.stream()
        .filter(employee -> employee.getAge() > 40)
        .map(Employee::getName)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: add a `.map(Employee::getName)` after `filter` to print the names or change the function to `forEach` to `forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()))`

Comment: Thank you that worked. Can you suggest any tutorials or resources where I can learn java lambdas.

Comment: Hey its actually printing out the reference of the object but not the name How do I change that.

Answer (score 0):

```
employees.stream().filter(e -> e.getAge() > 40).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
```